# H2 vs HSQLDB vs Derby | In-memory RDBMS for a Reporting APP

Tags: h2, derby, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I'm designing a Data REST API for the purpose of dynamic reporting. Basically, you pass in the data to it (along with the functions to manipulate the data) and it returns you a HTML with the functions applied on the data. Typically, these functions would be filtering, grouping, aggregating, sorting (what a regular RDBMS would offer). 
I'm contemplating as to use an in-memory DB for this. By doing so, I'll simply leverage the functions offered by the DB rather than having to implement myself.

However, this requires the service to load the data (perhaps bulk load) and then run series of queries constructed dynamically - as part of every service call.

The data (input) to be loaded in the database can be max 100K rows. Certainly not millions!

But the service can be accessed by different threads (each will load their data-set into the database and read concurrently). Of-course the jdbc connection will be pooled and the tables will be truncated at the end of every transaction.

I'm asking myself that am I going overboard and trying to exploit the in-memory dbs? I have used it myself (and often hear) about in-memory dbs (especially H2 and HSQL) only in the context of integration testing.

Would be interested to hear your views.

Comment: HSQLDB is used a lot in production in this type of configuration. It can operate in multi-threaded MVCC mode.

Comment: Both H2 and HSQLDB should work fine. Since recently, Derby also supports in-memory databases, but I have never used this so far, possibly it's a bit more complicated and slower.